# How to simulate monotonic data with constrained range?

Tags: lme4-nlme, simulation, statistical-power, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm running simulations for a power analysis for a negative binomial GLMM. The dependent variable has a negative binomial distribution and will be measured at five time points. It has two other characteristics I'm not sure of the most appropriate way to simulate. First, it has a maximum possible range of 0 - 128. Second, it's a cumulative lifetime score (representing lifetime incidence of [decayed, filled, or missing tooth surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay-missing-filled_index)), so by definition it can never decrease across time points -- only stay the same or increase.

**Short version:** I'm not sure how to appropriately account for this in my simulations. I'm considering (1) not worrying about it, (2) manually adding these constraints after simulating the data, or (3) simulating baseline and change-per-time point data separately, then combining. I'd appreciate input on which if any of these is appropriate, or other approaches I should try.

**Details:**

I'm simulating data using `lme4::simulate.formula()` as follows:

```r
library(lme4)
set.seed(13)

n_per_grp <- 125

simdata <- data.frame(
  id = rep(seq(n_per_grp * 2), each = 5),
  tx = factor(rep(c("mth", "sbx"), each = n_per_grp * 5)),
  xobs = rep(0:4, n_per_grp * 2)
)

y_sim <- simulate(
  ~ tx * xobs + (1 | id), 
  newdata = simdata, 
  newparams = list(
    beta = log(c(`(Intercept)` = 44.4, txsbx = 1.3, xobs = 1.01,`txsbx:xobs` = 1.4)),
    theta = 1
  ),
  family = negative.binomial(theta = 1.25)
)

simdata$y <- y_sim$sim_1

head(simdata)
#   id xobs  tx   y
# 1  1    0 mth  88
# 2  1    1 mth  19
# 3  1    2 mth 153
# 4  1    3 mth 225
# 5  1    4 mth   1
# 6  2    0 mth  39
```

As you can see, the simulated y values violate both characteristics: one of the values is 225, which obviously is >128, and the value decreases from 225 to 1 from follow-up #3 to #4.

I've considered three options to address this, and don't know which, if any, is appropriate.

**Option 1:** Don't worry about it and leave it as is. Maybe as long as the overall parameters are sound, the simulated data are a sufficient approximation even if some individual values are "implausible." The simulated data does approximately reproduce the input parameters:

```
m1 <- glmer.nb(y ~ tx * xobs + (1 | id), data = simdata)

exp(fixef(m1))
# (Intercept)       txsbx        xobs  txsbx:xobs 
#   37.238100    1.349626    1.029857    1.353801
```

**Option 2:** Manually "fix" the values after generating. I could add my constraints after simulating the data:

```
library(dplyr)

simdata2 <- simdata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(y = cummax(pmin(y, 128))) %>% 
  ungroup()

head(simdata2)
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#      id tx     xobs     y
#   <int> <fct> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 mth       0    88
# 2     1 mth       1    88
# 3     1 mth       2   128
# 4     1 mth       3   128
# 5     1 mth       4   128
# 6     2 mth       0    39
```

This doesn't seem ideal, as it obviously will change the distribution away from the input parameters. The intercept stays about the same, but the effect of time increases while the treatment effect and interaction decrease:

```
m2 <- glmer.nb(y ~ tx * xobs + (1 | id), data = simdata2)

exp(fixef(m2))
# (Intercept)       txsbx        xobs  txsbx:xobs 
#   37.333718    1.246907    1.158523    1.078400
```

**Option 3:** First simulate just baseline scores, then values representing change from previous time point, then get the cumulative sum across all time points.

```
simdata_split <- setNames(
  split(simdata, simdata$xobs == 0), 
  c("followup", "baseline")
)

y_sim_base <- simulate(
  ~ tx + (1 | id),
  newdata = simdata_split$baseline,
  newparams = list(
    beta = log(c(`(Intercept)` = 44.4, txsbx = 1.3)),
    theta = 1
  ),
  family = negative.binomial(theta = 1.25)
)

y_sim_followup <- simulate(
  ~ tx + (1 | id),
  newdata = simdata_split$followup,
  newparams = list(
    beta = log(c(`(Intercept)` = 44.4 / 100, txsbx = 1.4)),
    theta = 1
  ),
  family = negative.binomial(theta = 1.25)
)

simdata_split$baseline$y <- y_sim_base$sim_1
simdata_split$followup$y <- y_sim_followup$sim_1

simdata3 <- bind_rows(simdata_split) %>%
  arrange(id, xobs) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(y = cumsum(y)) %>% 
  ungroup()

head(simdata3, 10)
# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#       id tx     xobs     y
#    <int> <fct> <int> <dbl>
#  1     1 mth       0    50
#  2     1 mth       1    50
#  3     1 mth       2    50
#  4     1 mth       3    50
#  5     1 mth       4    50
#  6     2 mth       0   225
#  7     2 mth       1   225
#  8     2 mth       2   225
#  9     2 mth       3   226
# 10     2 mth       4   226
```

This addresses the monotonicity issue but not the 128 upper limit. But I don't know if it's appropriate to combine two separate simulations like this. I'm also not sure how to "translate" my parameters using this approach; this attempt certainly doesn't reproduce the input parameters:

```
m3 <- glmer.nb(y ~ tx * xobs + (1 | id), data = simdata3)
exp(fixef(m3))
# (Intercept)       txsbx        xobs  txsbx:xobs 
#  32.2105998   1.3895675   1.0105225   0.9958135
```

Comment: Several aspects of this question are concerning. First, it's a mathematical contradiction to posit a negative binomial distribution with an upper bound. Second, because these are cumulative results, they are strongly positively correlated, ruling out the applicability of most standard techniques.  Consider rethinking the approach. Perhaps directly modeling the changes in score would be more appropriate. By using a non-negative conditional response distribution, you would assure monotonicity. By including the cumulative sum among the variables, you might be able to enforce the upper threshold.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Can you say more about "a non-negative conditional response distribution"? (A Google search for "non-negative conditional response" turned up 0 results.) And what do you mean by "including the cumulative sum among the variables" -- presumably you don't mean as a predictor.

Comment: Re "because these are cumulative results, they are strongly positively correlated" -- is that not addressed by the use of random intercepts per subject? i.e., in any repeated-measures design, a subject's score at time *t* is usually dependent on their score at time *t* - 1, whether or not the score is irreversible, and using random intercepts accounts for this dependence, no?

Comment: That would handle correlations among *the individual scores.*  The kind of (extremely strong) correlation and monotonicity induced by accumulating the scores will not be adequately addressed with a random intercepts model.  You can improve your Web searching by including a focusing keyword like [GLM](https://www.google.com/search?q=non-negative+conditional+response+glm).  And yes, I do mean using the cumsum as a predictor.  Many time series analysis methods do essentially that.

Comment: @whuber might a beta binomial distribution be more appropriate?